# C99 - Conceptual understanding of 2D Array assignment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc

I was trying to looking for ways to assign 2D arrays on the heap in C, and I ran into something I've never seen before. My usual method of assigning 2D arrays is to create an array of pointers and then fill that array with pointers to other arrays. What I'm trying to understand is the line

```
int (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*array));
```

Here's my current understanding of it:

1) We allocate some space on the heap for all the rows we want, multiplied by the size of a single column.

2) `malloc()` then returns a pointer to this address on the heap, which we then assign to (*array)?

My confusion mostly stems from the usage of (*array). Could someone please give me a run through of why we can use (*array) in this case? Also, why would `sizeof(*array)` return the size (in bytes), of each column?

Answer (score 1):

The code is using a pointer to a variable-length array (VLA), and allocating enough memory for `rows` rows (multiply the size of one row, `sizeof(*array)`, by the number of rows).  I'm assuming both `rows` and `cols` are variables, not constants.  (Constant names are conventionally written in all upper-case: `ROWS` and `COLS`, for example.)

The assignment is to `array`, not `*array` — and it is formally an initialization, not an assignment.  The `*` is part of the type; this is a declaration (and definition) of `array`.  The notation with the mandatory parentheses is how you declare or define a pointer to an array in C:

```
int (*array)[cols];
```

This too is a legitimate definition of a pointer to an array of `int` of size `cols`.  You could then assign to it:

```
array = malloc(rows * sizeof(array[0]));
```

or:

```
array = malloc(rows * sizeof(*array));
```

The pointer points to the zeroth row of the array, so you can now use code like this to access the data:

```
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        array[r][c] = rand() % 128;
}
```